FastAPI Rendering html Loading script module with wrong mime type
When rendering html file with tag <script type="module" crossorigin src="/static/assets/index-DIiKvbdV.js"></script> it is required that the mime type responds correctly, and I don't know how to deal with this in Fastapi.
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
app.mount("/main/assets", StaticFiles(directory="static/assets"), name="static")

@app.get("/")
async def redirect_to_static():
    return RedirectResponse(url="/main")


@app.get("/main", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def static_endpoint(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("static/index.html", {"request": request})

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/static/assets/index-DIiKvbdV.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/static/assets/index-CMasdhyl.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>

  </body>
</html>

Chrome console gives error when access /main  ,  (rendering index.html)
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

fastapi 0.89.1
Pydantic 1.10.15
Python 3.10.3

First import and add this statement at the top,
import mimetypes
custom_mimetype = mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)

Add mimetypes argument to the TemplateResponse() like this,
@app.get("/main", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def static_endpoint(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("static/index.html", {"request": request}, mimetypes=custom_mimetype)

Now the error will go away.

line 81, in static_endpoint
return templates.TemplateResponse("static/index.html", {"request": request}, mimetypes=custom_mimetype)
TypeError: Jinja2Templates.TemplateResponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetypes'

Which version of Jinja2 you use? I use 3.1.3, it works in that version. Upgrade the version and try again

Upgraded to Jinja2==3.1.3, it works. Thanks.

Please try force refresh, the html page might be cached
